# React best practice of 'componentisation' of ul and li elements

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I am learning React and need some guidance from you. I am planning to implement a menu based on `<ul>`.

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="/link1">Menu One</a></li>
  <li><a href="/link2">Menu Two</a></li>
</ul>
```

Can I convert the above list to:

```
<MenuContainer>
    <MenuItem text="Menu One" target="/link1" />
    <MenuItem text="Menu Two" target="/link2" />
</MenuContainer>
```

My main problem is how to render `<MainContainer>` component since I have to include all its sub-components within the opening (`<ul>`) and closing tags (`</ul>`).

**Update 1**

Header.js:

```
<MenuHeader target="EnterpriseMenuContainer" text="Enterprise" />
<MenuContainer id="EnterpriseMenuContainer">
    <MenuItemLink text="Company" target="/companies" />
    <MenuItemLink text="Site" target="/sites" />
</MenuContainer>
```

MenuHeader.js (only `render()`): *(this is working)*

```
return (
  <li>
    <span onClick={this.handleMenuHeaderClick}>
      {this.props.text}
    </span>
  </li>
)
```

MenuItemLink.js (only `render()`):

```
return (
  <li><a href={this.props.target}>{this.props.text}</a></li>
)
```

I have no idea how to write `MenuContainer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you render your component as

You are essentially passing `MenuItem's` as children to `MenuContainer`. So you cna write MenuContainer as

```
const MenuContainer = ({children}) => {
   return <ul>{children}</ul>
}
```

and MenuItem as

```
const MenuItem = ({ text, target}) => {
     return <li><a href={target}>{text}</a><li>
}
```

and it will replicate your structure of

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="/link1">Menu One</a></li>
  <li><a href="/link2">Menu Two</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. But I couldn't understand (due to my lack of knowledge). Let me update the question with what I have written so far so that you can take a look and show where the issue is.

Comment: @LakmalPremaratne As I said in the post, anything written between `MenuContainer` tags, that is passed on to the ccomponent as children prop and then you render those children prop inside MenuContainer. And I have added how you would write a MenuContainer in my post